# How to start Edmonds-Karp implementation if all the paths have same lengths?

Tags: c++, algorithm, network-flow, edmonds-karp

How can I select the starting path for the [Edmonds-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) if all the paths are the same length? In this case, maximum flow changes according to path sequence decision.

Comment: What do you mean maximum flow changes? The maximum flow in a network has always the same value. The only reason for Edmonds-Karp to choose the shortest path with respect for number of edges is to avoid edge cases where the performance of the algorithm suffers greatly with respect to speed, not result.

Comment: a b 3|||
b y 9|||
x c 10|||
x a 6|||
c d 5|||
a d 3|||
c b 7|||
d y 7|||
a 10|||
d 6|||
c 8|||
b 12|||
first 8 lines shows the capacities of edges and the nodes connected with these edges.(a b 3 means there is direction from a to b). and last 4 lines shows the capacities of nodes. x is the root and y is the destination.
If I use following sequnce
x-c-d-y 5|||
x-c-b-y 3|||
x-a-d-y 1|||
x-a-b-y 3|||
I got 12. (In every line I send maximum flow that i can send.)

Comment: However if I follow following sequence
x-a-b-y 3|||
x-a-d-y 3|||
x-c-d-y 3|||
x-c-b-y 5|||
I got 14 in total. Either I have a silly mistake, or there is a rule if all paths have same lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with how you handle capacities at the vertices. The usual way this is done is by splitting the vertex v in two vertices v' and v'' and adding an edge between v' and v'' with the capacity of the vertex. All edges connected to v(i.e. for which v is destination) should be connected with v' in the new graph and all edges from v should start from v'' in the new graph.

You probably know that when you let flow x-a-b-y 3 you add to the capacity of the reverse edges. In that case you will add the edges a x 3, b a 3, y b 3. If you do the graph representation as I described you will see that there is additional flow you can use in the first case(I think it can pass through x-a-d-c-b-y, but have not checked it).

The selection of the shortest path should not change the answer - as I mentioned in my comment we only select the shortest path on each step to avoid bad cases where the performance suffers, but the answer is always the same.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I know i should split the vertices to handle with vertex capacities but i subtract the passed flow capacity from all edges instead of adding reverse edges. Since I did not add any reverse edge, there is no paths like x-a-d-c-b-y. Now, i get the idea. Thank you for your answer.